Longitudinal analysis
I have a question. Suppose that I want to analyze if a particular variable "X" affects the incidence of a disease "D," but I do not have the information about "D" at the baseline. If I use survival analysis, I have to remove all people with D at baseline, and then I can perform models for time to event. In this case, I can not do it. Is there some model that supposes a similar distribution of the variable "X" at baseline and then studies how to evolve during the follow-up? In order to see if the variable "X" affect "D"?
Thanks!

What data do you u have? What time points? What sample size? When do you get info on D?
